# Filter List using Underscore JS with unique field value

Tags: angularjs, filter, underscore.js

I have a list of Object. I want to get unique list by a column. 
For Example,  I have

```
[
{ "city" : "Dhaka",
  "temp" : 30,
   "grade": "A"
},

{ "city" : "Comilla",
  "temp" : 32,
   "grade": "B"
},
{ "city" : "Sylhet",
  "temp" : 32,
   "grade": "A"
},
{ "city" : "Noakhali",
  "temp" : 32,
   "grade": "C"
}
]
```

I want to get when i give column '`grade`'

```
[
    { 
       "grade": "A"
    },
    { 
       "grade": "B"
    },
    { 
       "grade": "C"
    }

    ]
```

When i used this,

```
$scope.listOfFilterdItems = _($scope.dataList).chain().flatten().pluck('grade').unique().value();
```

I got array of Strings
["A","B","C"]

I don't want it. I need object list. 
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**pick**](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) instead of pluck:

```
var result = _.chain(data)
    .map(function(city){
        return _.pick(city, 'grade')        
    })
    .uniq('grade')
    .value();
```

**Edit**

The function passed to map can be changed to cater for renaming the filtered key as *filter*:

```
var gradeToFilter = function(city){
    return {
        filter: city.grade
    }
}

var result = _.chain(data)
    .map(gradeToFilter)
    .uniq('filter')
    .value();
```

```js
var data = [
  { "city" : "Dhaka",
    "temp" : 30,
     "grade": "A"
  },

  { "city" : "Comilla",
    "temp" : 32,
     "grade": "B"
  },
  { "city" : "Sylhet",
    "temp" : 32,
     "grade": "A"
  },
  { "city" : "Noakhali",
    "temp" : 32,
     "grade": "C"
  }
 ];


var result1 = _.chain(data)
 .map(function(city){
  return _.pick(city, 'grade')  
 })
 .uniq('grade')
 .value();
 
var gradeToFilter = function(city){
    return {
        filter: city.grade
    }
}

var result2 = _.chain(data)
    .map(gradeToFilter)
    .uniq('filter')
    .value();

document.getElementById('result1').textContent = JSON.stringify(result1);
document.getElementById('result2').textContent = JSON.stringify(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result1"></pre>
</p>

<p>
  <pre id="result2"></pre>
</p>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Oops you're right  - I left a trailing } at the end of the code.

Comment: Is it possible to alias it as  ` [
    { 
       "filter": "A"
    },
    { 
       "filter": "B"
    },
    { 
       "filter": "C"
    }

    ]`

always....either i filter by "grade" or "temp"

Comment: It works! but for alias...but it is not giving unique value now.  It shows full list.

Comment: Extended the code snippet to include the bit that uses filter as a key